# How might one except hidden '.' files and directories from a script that renames them?

Tags: shell-script, find, regular-expression, rename, recursive

I have a script that renames, getting rid off the whitespace, every directory and file. It does it recursively:

```
#!/bin/bash

find -name "* *" -print0 | sort -rz | \
  while read -d $'\0' f; do mv -v "$f" "$(dirname "$f")/$(basename "${f// /_}")"; done
```

When I ran it in my `~` directory, the script wrought some unintended havoc renaming the following items:

- `./.cache/google-chrome/Default/Storage/ext/nmmhkkegccagdldgiimedpiccmgmieda/def/Code Cache`
- `./.cache/google-chrome/Default/Storage/ext/gfdkimpbcpahaombhbimeihdjnejgicl/def/Code Cache`
- `./.cache/google-chrome/Default/Code Cache`

I would like my script to except any directory or file that starts with `.` from renaming it. How would you write such a script? Does one need to use regular expressions for this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `zsh`'s `zmv`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
autoload -Uz zmv
zmv '(**/)(* *)' '$1${2// /_}'
```

- `zmv` skips hidden files and files in hidden dirs by default (unless you pass a `(#qD)` qualifier to the first argument),
- it processes the files *depth first* (your `sort -rz` is not guaranteed to work for that and `-prune` is not compatible with `-depth`)
- we don't need to call `dirname`/`basename` (which would be expensive and not work properly with command substitution if there are some file names ending in newline characters).
- it doesn't have `find` problems whereby `*` don't match arbitrary sequences of bytes.
- If there are some conflicts (like when there's both a `a b c` and `a_b c` files which would both be renamed to `a_b_c`), it will detect it at the start  and abort before doing any rename.

To do something approaching with GNU tools, that would be something like:

```
#! /bin/bash -
export LC_ALL=C
while IFS= read <&3 -rd '' file; do
  dir=${file%/*} name=${file##*/}
  mv -i -- "$file" "$dir/${name// /_}"
done 3< <(
  find . -name '.?*' -prune -o -name '* *' -print0 |
    tac -s '')
```

Here,

- setting the locale to `C` so `*` matches any sequence of bytes, not just those forming valid characters in the user's locale, and `?` matches a single byte. Beware though that the messages (errors, prompts...) will then be issued in English instead of the user's language.
- `-name '.?*' -prune -o ...` skips hidden files and tells `find` not to descend into hidden directories.
- Passing `-i` to `mv` to guard against clobbering files unintentionally.
- Passing the list of files over fd 3 instead of stdin, so `mv -i` prompt works.
- Using `tac -s ''` instead of `sort -rz` to reverse the output to ensure leaves are renamed before the branches they're on.
- replacing `dirname`/`basename` with the standard `${var##pattern}` and `${var%pattern}` parameter expansion operators.
- also passing `-r` to `read` to disable its special handling of backslashes.
- making sure that for `read` `$IFS` is empty, so it doesn't remove trailing white space from the input records.

Comment: Why did you use `?` in `find . -name '.?*' -prune -o -name '* *' -print0` instead of `'.{1,1}*'` or `'.*'`? Doesn't `?` mean optionality here? Why would you prune the results that may not start with `.`?

Comment: @JohnSmith, no `-name` takes a glob / `fnmatch()` pattern, not a regexp. So in there `?` matches any single character, the equivalent of regexp `.`. So `-name '.?*'` matches any file name starting with `.` followed by  one character followed by any number of characters so it matches hidden files excluding `.` (the starting file) itself. A regex equivalent would be `^\...*$` or with extended regexp: `^\..+$`, or without anchoring at the end: `^\..` (starts with `.` followed by one character)

Answer (score 5):

Without looking too much at the other commands in the pipeline, you can make `find` avoid entering any directory that has a hidden name:

```
find . ! -path . -name '.*' -prune -o -name '* *' -print0 | ...
```

This will remove all directories that have `.` at the start of their names from the search tree, except for the `.` directory (the current directory).  It will also no longer find hidden names at all.

---

Having looked at the rest of your code, I would recommend using `rename` (the Perl variant) instead:

```
find . ! -path . -name '.*' -prune \
    -o -type f -name '* *' -execdir rename -n -v 'tr/ /_/' {} \;
```

This would do a search for filenames containing spaces, and then replace all the spaces in them with underscores, while ignoring hidden names and not entering hidden directories.

The `rename` utility is invoked with `-n` to stop it from actually doing anything (it's a "dry run").  Remove `-n` when you are confident that it's doing the right thing.

Without `rename`, you would do something like

```
find . ! -path . -name '.*' -prune \
    -o -type f -name '* *' -exec bash -c '
    for pathname do
        filename=${pathname##*/}
        echo mv "$pathname" "${pathname%/*}/${filename// /_}"
    done' bash {} +
```

That is, call an in-line `bash` script that iterates over the found names, renaming each by changing spaces to underscores.

Remove the `echo` when you're confident this does the right thing.

Comment: Note that the OP asked for every file and directory to be renamed, while this only renames *regular* files.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, I am aware, thanks. I'm also somewhat busy, so it will take a while to get back to this.

Comment: Also beware that with some `find` implementations including GNU `find` or GNU systems, that fails to exclude hidden files if their path cannot be decoded as text in the user's locale and will not rename the files with spaces in their name if that name also contains sequence of bytes that can't be decoded as text in the user's locale. For instance, it would not rename a `$'St\xe9phane Chazelas.jpg'` to `$'St\xe9phane_Chazelas.jpg'` if run in a locale with UTF-8 as the charmap.